# "no-unused-variable": true is not working in VSCode

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, tslint

I am trying to use `tslint` with typescript in an `Ionic3` project. When I add `"no-unused-variable": true` in the tslint.json, it has no effect. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the code editor feature to remove the unused import variables. e.g. vscode provide a feature [run-code-actions-on-save](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_run-code-actions-on-save)

Add below config in your `settings.json` file of vscode:

```
{
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
    }
  }
}
```

It will remove the unused import variables and organize your import statement.

Comment: excellent suggession for vscode!
But, if you work on on a project which develıopers use both vscode and webstorm or other kind of ide or text editors, you will always face conflicts or meanless line changes

Comment: What if some module need to import but not necessary used ?

Answer (score 2):

People have reported problems with that rule while using VSCode.

A potential fix is to remove it from your `tslint.json`, and replace it with `"noUnusedLocals": true` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Where should I put "noUnusedLocals": true. Inside "compilerOptions" block or a the root block?

Comment: That would go in the `compilerOptions` block

Comment: Just a note that this will break your build which gets annoying really fast when you're doing iterative development locally.  This is why the TSLint rule was NOT deprecated in favor of the TS compiler option.